# PL/SQL : Example for select and update the record based on certain rule

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have situation something like below...

```
select * from tableA A

if A.salary > 100 and A.years > 0 then
update tableA set A.level = '1' where A.id = id;
else if A.salary > 200  A.years > 1 then
update tableA set A.level = '2' where A.id = id;
else 
update tableA set A.level = '0' where A.id = id;
end if
```

how i can implement this in PL/SQL? above situation is just an example.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do this in PL/SQL; it can be done in a single UPDATE statement by using a [CASE expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037):

```
update tablea
   set level = case when salary > 100 and years > 0 then 1
                    when salary > 200 and years > 1 then 2
                    else 0
               end
```

It's worth noting that "level" is a reserved word (it's a psuedocolumn used for Oracle's hierarchical queries) and can cause problems if you use it. I'd choose something else if possible.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes you're right. But this is just sample. I would like to select all in 1st process, and then 2nd process will do many thing, such as insert, update, based on 1st process.

Comment: I would ask another question then explaining exactly what you want to then @Sh4m.

Comment: Hi Ben, i just update some process above, insert into tableB and tableC based on rules.

the idea is, once get all the records from 1st step, 2nd step will get each records and process..

Comment: If you have a question different to the one you asked @Sh4m please [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question. If you explain exactly what you're attempting to do it will help you get an answer. Please don't alter your current questions when you already have answers.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes sorry for that. im still new in stackoverflow. Do you have any idea how to implement this? 

apperciate your help.